# Fix too high DPI causing extremely large text and graphics in desktop mode (but not in Modern UI) on a Windows 8.1 tablet

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution, dpi

I have an HP stream 7. Resolution in metro looks perfect, but desktop mode is so low that I cannot change any settings.

Please look at the screenshots. Any idea on how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Does that thing have an external monitor option? Is the command line usable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything was too large to be able to modify the DPI in the slider in the control panel.

I went to the registry to

HKCU/Control Panel/Desktop and changed 'LogPixels' to 120 (it was at 480).

Logging out and logging back in fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Charms bar, select **Search**, and search for **Make text and other items larger or smaller**, then try dragging the DPI slider all the way to the left. Then tap the **Apply** button at the bottom of the window. You may need to scroll down to see the slider or Apply button.

[image: DPI adjustment in Windows 8]

Comment: I couldn't even see the slider when I opened the page